# If $f$ and $g$ are two permutations on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ such that none of them has a cycle of length $5$, is it possible for $f \circ g$ ...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If $f$ and $g$ are two permutations on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ such that none of them has a cycle of length $5$, is it possible for $f \circ g$ to have a cycle of length $5$?

I think this is possible because I have seen some composite permutations where the resulting permutation has a cycle of greater length than any of the two permutations in the composition. However I do not know how to approach this problem and prove it, I can just create an example where this is true but I want to know how to show that it is true without creating an example.

I do not think that the inverse permutation or the identity permutation would help me in this situation, any ideas of what I can do without telling me the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(a b c)(c d e) = (a b c d e)$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this, $(abc)$ and $(cde)$ are not in the same set?

Comment: He/she is just using letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Yup. $(abc)$ is just a 3-cycle like $(123)$

Comment: I understand that, but does he mean $f=(123)$ and $g=(345)$? Then it doesn't make sense to do $f \circ g$, if he means that $f=(123)(345)$ then how can $3$ point to $1$ and $4$?

Comment: $((123)(345))(5)=(123)((345)(5))=(123)(3)=1$. Check yourself that every other element remains "unchanged" (their destination is still the same as in $f$ or $g$, accordingly)